# Laravel 5: Error: "Driver not found" while migrating the database(mysql) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

It's been around 5-6 hours since I've been trying to use database in laravel 5.

I've gone through of videos and it confused me a lot.

I have created the model and migration but when i try to migrate it gives me an

> [ PDOException ] Driver not found

I've made numerous changes to .env and database.php but nothing works.

I am using laravel 5 with xampp server.

Kindly help

Thank you

**.env** file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=zZfvju3BKjxmLKbl5gsVJ3ymkIvHbGNq

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=medicaldb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

database.php file

```
<?php

return [
    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'medicaldb'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
        ],

    ],


    'migrations' => 'migrations',
    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: Please share your  .env file and database.php details

Comment: You should only be setting the database connection in the .env file. This provides protection of your database.php if it's ever compromised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, at last! it worked!!

In php.ini file:

(semi-colon) ; works as a single-line comment in php.ini file.
(semi-colon) was added at the beginning of the line - which disables pdo mysql driver.

I just needed to remove the semi-colon(;) to enable mysql, from the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, ubuntu 17.10, Laravel 5.6

It is the issue normally come when you upgrade you php version I get the same issues in my lammp stack while i update from php 7 to 7.1 I get Solve by following command

- Open Terminal
- sudo apt install php7.1-pdo php7.1-mysql

*Have fun with Code*

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have mysql intalled? also, please check pdo_mysql module is enabled. use phpinfo();

Comment: Thanks !

I've checked the phpinfo of xammp.
and i could only see pdo_sqlite section
and nothing related to pdo_mysql


Please tell me how can i install mysql in xampp for laravel.

Comment: If you are using xampp, it should have been included already . Try installing a new version of xammp and copy your project there. Guess you are working in windows.

Comment: I have installed the latest version of xampp
and still couldn't find pdo_mysql under phpinfo in xampp.


is there any way to explicitly install mysql for xampp??

Comment: add the following lines in your php.ini
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll.  restart server. Again, I guess you are working in windows envronment

Comment: Yes!
I am using windows 10.
I have added those lines
and still it's is not working.

Comment: Restarted the webserver using your xamp control panel?

Comment: yes!
I have restarted it every time i made any changes.

Comment: Can you please [try this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296203.aspx)